# meaning of xpath Notations

Tags: xpath

I want to know, what is the meaning of below symbols while calculating `xpath`.

> ., @, |, [], /, //, //*

I mean if for eg. `xpath` is `.//*[@id='Table2']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`
then what is the explanation of the same.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Thanks..Got Answer here.